# IOS 11 - Over the Air Release

Tags: ios, ios11, udid, ota

Will iOS 11 supports OTA release using the .plist and .html?. Before it was worked using Dropbox, But recently which is not supported in iOS 11. Is there any other option we have?

Answer (score 3):

Sure it does. Just create your manifest.plist, upload it (together with the ipa) to some reachable server, and provide the `itms-services` - Link to the manifest, and there you go.

Nevertheless, you need to ensure that everything works fine, expecially:

- The server has to provide the correct "MIME" type for the files
- I think you need to use https
- The app has to be signed + provisioned correctly, like for enterprise deployment or contain the device IDs.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please also mark it.